# Rearrange a list based on given order in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, sorting

I have a list as follows:

```
{CT, MA, VA, NY}
```

I submit this list to a function and I get the optimum waypoint order list

```
{2,0,1,3}
```

Now I have to rearrange the list as per the order that is newly provided. i.e. after rearranging, the list should look like:

```
{VA, CT, MA, NY}
```

What is the optimum way to do it? Using linq is there a way?

Comment: LINQ ALL THE THINGS!!!!11111ONEONE.  But seriously, just because you are manipulating a list, does not mean you should use Linq.  In fact, this one is simple enough that using Linq probably overcomplicates it

Comment: @cadrell0, while your point is well taken, there is nothing complicated about the Linq on this one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
var list = new List<string>{"CT", "MA", "VA", "NY"};
var order = new List<int>{2, 0, 1, 3};
var result = order.Select(i => list[i]).ToList();
```

Comment: @weston The question clearly states that - no assumptions here :)

Comment: Awesome solution: just to clearify whats happening here: the list "order" sort of assigns a new order value to the old list in the order of the existing list. so basically stating that: CT now is 2, MA = 0, VA = 1 and NY = 3. Next we are cycling trough the existing list and selecting the items by its index with the new order. the final "toList()" then puts it back onto a list "result" which is the same exact list as before (even with many properties to the list) only in the desired order. its a very smart and quick solution.

Answer (score 8):

This seems like the simplest approach:

```
oldItems = LoadItems(); //{"CT","MA","VA","NY"};
List<string> newItems = List<string>();
foreach(int idx in returnedIndexes)
{
   newItems.Add(oldItems[idx]);
}
```